# Menu with z-index (transition)

Tags: html, css

I have in my header a menu, but I have a problem with it.
So here is the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FZ4r/), and some of my code:

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
  <div class="onglet">
    <a href="/"><div class="btn ">2</div></a>
    <div class="topbar-dialog hidden">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">XX<br/><span class="item-summary">xx</span></a></li>
             <li><a href="">xx<br/><span class="item-summary">xx xxxxx xxxxx</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (just a part)

```
.topbar-dialog.hidden{margin-top:-450px;-webkit-transition:.5s;z-index:-1;}
```

So there is a problem. As you can see, the menu appear under the text ... And if I set `z-index:-2;` to the text, the menu become useless ...

Maybe someone can help me ...

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that the menu should also go behind the `<div id="menu">`

Comment: Using a positive z-index seems to work - setting z-index to `1` http://jsfiddle.net/8FZ4r/1/

Comment: Changing the z-index from `z-index:-1;` to `z-index:100;` seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8FZ4r/4/

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention that the menu should also go behind the menu block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if is a good solution, but it works.

First, in your div `<div id="menu">` add a new div (empty) `<div class="layout"></div>`.
And think to change the position (to `relative`) of the parent div. Here is the CSS:

```
#menu{background:#D5D5D5;text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #eee;position:relative;}
#menu .layout{position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;z-index:99;background:#D5D5D5}
```

And then, just add a `z-index:2` to your menu.
Here is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/8FZ4r/5/

Answer (score 0):

You have a z-index: -1 after your CSS transition. It's easier to see if you "tidy" the code in jsfiddle. Removing it seems to accomplish what you want. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8FZ4r/3/

Relevant snippet, edited:

```
.topbar-dialog.hidden {
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color:#fff;
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index:999;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    border-left:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-right:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin-top:-450px;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention that the menu should also go behind the menu block

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `z-index` to a positive value.